# Can Visual Studio remote debugging be done over a local network?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

I've been unable to get Visual Studio, running on my development machine, to successfully deploy to a Surface Book on my local network. Error message is included below. On the Surface Book I've installed Remote Tools for Visual Studio, and set up Developer Mode. VS on my development machine shows me the SB, and allows me to select if from a list of deployment targets, including it's Authentication type, but deployment fails.

There is a "pair" option on the SB, which I haven't been able to make work & I'm not sure if it's necessary. In addition, I saw a post saying this option (local network) was no longer supported. Is it still supported, and if so, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Error Message:
Error       DEP6957: Failed to connect to device '10.0.0.179' using Universal Authentication. Please verify the correct remote authentication mode is specified in the project debug settings. COMException - Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component. [0x80004005]

Comment: Yes it can, I've done it many times before. It can also be done over the internet, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To remote debug a uwp app, we should install the corresponding version Remote Tools for Visual Studio, before we can deploy the app to the remote device, we should configure the Remote Debugger tool. See the [Run UWP apps on a remote machine in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/run-windows-store-apps-on-a-remote-machine) for details.

For your this issue, it should be you select the **Windows authentication mode** in your Visual Studio as the follow image, but you don't have access to the credentials of the signed-in user of the target machine. In your VS, you should use the credentials of the signed-in user of the target machine to deploy your app when the VS popup the permission window. See the [Authentication modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/deploying-and-debugging-uwp-apps#authentication-modes) to learn the differences.

[image]

On the other hand, you can also try to use the **None authentication mode** to remote deploy your app as the following steps.

Firstly, in the Visual Studio Remote Debugger of the target device, select Tools=> Options to configure the options Window as bellow,

[image]

Then in your Visual studio, right click your UWP project=> properties=> Debug to cofigure it as **None authentication mode**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Breeze Liu was very helpful, and got me most of the way to the solution. The final step that I was missing was to add my account to the Remote Debugger's permission list. It's found at Remote Debugger>Tools>Permissions. I had to add my account on the target machine to the list of "permitted" debuggers.